# Last 3 months of block in the blockchain are taking forever to load

Tags: blockchain

I am downloading the blockchain. It's currently at 20-40 blocks loaded per minute, while I've been able to load the first 128GB in 2h, which represents 96% of the chain. There only remains 80k blocks, but they are extremely slow to load. It's going to require tens of hours for these. Why? Is something different in the latest blocks from the past months? My internet is going well.

EDIT : 9 hours later I have loaded 20% more of the remaining. It is going to last 2 or 3 days for these last 3 percents.

Comment: What kind of drive are you syncing the blockchain too?

Comment: SSD (intel 660p)

Comment: Apologies for the late response. Did it eventually complete? An SSD should normally result in the sync being relatively fast. Could you divulge some other information regarding your setup?